# What's Squeryl syntax for exclusion (i.e. != )?

Tags: scala, squeryl

Doing a simple Squeryl database lookup, but trying to exclude a value. I've tried:

`j.id not jobExclude` and `j.id != jobExclude`

however the first triggers a compiler error and the second triggers a runtime error.

The whole transaction:

```
from(DB.jobs)(j =>
      where((j.startTime >= todayStart)
      and (j.startTime <= todayEnd)
      and (j.userId === userId)
      and (j.teamId === teamId)
      and (j.startOrder >= index)
      and (j.id not jobExclude))
      select (j)).toList
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of the Squeryl Groups:

Not equals is `<>`

so in the bigger picture:

`(job.id <> jobExclude)`

See http://squeryl.org/functions.html

Credit https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/squeryl/Hw7iVyvLLNM